# SyntaxError: Unexpected token > for nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs script that runs just fine on my macbook. I tried running it on a Linux 6.9 machine, and it's throwing SyntaxErrors.

Below is the script :

```
var readInfinitely = function(iterator, dirName,onFileContent,onError){
    var circIter = iterator;
    fname = circIter.next().value;
    fs.readFileAsync(dirName + fname,'utf8').then(data => //THIS IS 
                                                      //WHERE IT ERRORS
        {

            onFileContent(data);
            readInfinitely(circIter, dirName,onFileContent,onError)

    })
}
```

It does not like "=>" . How can I fix this?

EDIT
Running v0.10.48
Was using Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) on my mac to edit this. Not sure if it has any effect.

Comment: This might be a node version error or an IDE javascript version error

Comment: Updated post to include versions. Running the latest version of node.

Comment: What is throwing the error? running the code with `node script.js` or the IDE editor

Comment: Running the code with `node script.js` is throwing the error @Derek

Comment: Yeah, your node version is super outdated. Check this out: https://node.green/

Comment: You are running **v0.10** and the latest is **v10**

Answer (score 0):

What version of Node are you running?  It could be that your version of Node is old and doesn't have [lambdas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) implemented.  You can find out by running `node -v` in the terminal on your Linux machine.  If Node is older than v6 it needs to be updated for your code to work.

Also, if for some reason upgrading Node is not an option, you could replace `data => {...}` with `function(data) {...}` and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Hi, using  version of nodejs. v0.10.48
Updated the post with that info too.

Comment: I think Node's version corresponds to the version of Javascript it is running, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @user2405589 you should probably install a newer version of Node then...  [The latest version is 10.3.0](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).

Answer (score 0):

=> stands for arrow function or lambda function and is part of ECMA2015 or (ES6), which is supported by node version 6 and above, so you need to update your node version.